# Table cell sizing in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a [HTML table](http://jsfiddle.net/alirezamirian/TgxJa/)
Required details are mentioned in JSFiddle.
This is working well on Firefox, but it's not on Chrome and IE!
what's wrong with them? why they expand the cell in the last row which has a fixed height, instead of second row which is the only cell with not-determined height in first column.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" dir="rtl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="height: 100px; width: 176px; background:blue">
        this is a fixed size cell
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="background:gray; height: 360px;">this cell is spanned 3 rows<br /> lots of content may be placed here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background:red">this should expand depending on gray region</td>
</tr>

<tr>    
    <td style="height: 46px; background:blue">this is a fixed size cell</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like height algorithm for your case is underfind. You want `td {height: auto}` to extend all available space, but

> A 'height' value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used
>   for layout is MIN. MIN depends on cell box heights and cell box
>   alignment....In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content

and finaly

> CSS 2.1 does not specify how cells that span more than one row affect
>   row height calculations except that the sum of the row heights
>   involved must be great enough to encompass the cell spanning the rows.

see [17.5.3 Table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. But what can I do for my situation? I want to implement such a layout in a cross-browser way, no matter how.

Comment: Is width of column (both left and right or one of them) fixed? Or can it be set in percent?

Comment: Yes, width is fixed, but as I mentioned, the height of the gray cell is variable, and the height of red cell should be variable depending on height of the gray cell

Comment: You can rid of table and use position:absolute for the right col and cells on the top and at the bottom. See demo on fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2LReu/4/)

Comment: yeah, you're right, and thank you for your Jsfiddle example. But this way the red region actually covers all of the right column, which cause a problem for my situation, because top and bottom cells in the right column have kinda semi-transparent background, and the background of middle cell (which is the red region in your example) should not exceed the middle area of the right column. in other word, I just exactly what you've created, except that I want the middle cell to be red, not the whole right column with some top and bottom area attached on it!

Comment: you can position absolute central cell, just choose right top and bottom verges [see update](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_007/2LReu/8/)

Comment: Dear Vicky, thank u very very much. It works! :D actually I had tried something like this before, except that I didn't know it's possible to set both "top" and "bottom" (or "left and "right") for an absolutely positioned element. Thank U again for your help.